# The method split(String) is undefined for the type List<String>

Tags: java, string, split

I am making a small program to split sentences when detecting a dot

I am struggling to print the result

```
// print result list
for(int i = 0; i < fileContent.size(); i++) {
    String[] fileContent1 = (fileContent).split("\\.");
}
```

the function split is not working and on eclipse I got this error message :
*The method split(String) is undefined for the type List*

I understand the error message, I tried to cast the result but not working.

Do you have any ideas ?

Thank you for your explanations and help :)

Update 1

Thank for your reply,

I think it is better to put the full loop to understand better 
Indeed I made a mistake its a list of String

```
// print result list

for(int i = 0; i < fileContent.size(); i++) 
{
    List<String> fileContent1 = fileContent.split("\\.");

    System.out.println(fileContent.get(i));     

    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("C:/Users/Jer/Desktop/outputfile.txt")); 
    //out.print("Hello "); 
    out.print(fileContent); 
    out.close();
}
```

Update 2 :

Well I got any error message :) thank you very much I will continue to debug my code on my side now

Comment: Please also avoid "Thank you" and similar comments at the end of the question (but thank you for your courtesy!) We'd prefer "just the facts".

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to

```
for(String singleFileContent: fileContent) {
    String[] fileContent1 = singleFileContent.split("\\.");
}
```

Seems like the fileContent is a List and not a String.

You code also do it like (as mention in an other answer)

```
for(int i = 0; i < fileContent.size(); i++) {
   String[] fileContent1 = fileContent.get(i).split("\\.");
}
```

Comment: This is probably what you want +1

Comment: Must be by someone who doesn't know how to write code ... ;) :P

Answer (score 1):

Judging from your error message, I'm guessing `fileContent` is of type `List<String>`. If so, you probably want to do something like:

```
for (String fc : fileContent) {
    String[] fileContent1 = fc.split("\\.");
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Yes exactly the goal of my programm is to read a text file, detect dot to split the sentences and write them into a output text file

Comment: So you read the file line by line (I'd recommend using for instance a `BufferedReader.readLine` or `Scanner.nextLine`) and put the lines in `fileContent`? If so, the above code should work. If you then need to loop over the sentences, you do `for (String sentence : fileContent1) { System.out.println(sentence); }` right where I've written `// ...`.

Answer (score 1):

`fileContent` is of type `List` and not `String`, as indicated in the compiler message. The `split` method should be called against a `String` object. If the list contains `String` elements, and you want to split each element in the list, you need to `get` the element first:

```
for(int i = 0; i < fileContent.size(); i++) {
       String[] fileContent1 = fileContent.get(i).split("\\.");
}
```